# Not able to handler InternalAuthenticationServiceException in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

I am developing a rest api using Spring Boot. I have a class that extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, where I override the `attemptAuthentication` method. In the process of authentication, Spring internally uses my `CustomUserDetailsService` that throws an exception in case no user is found. Spring internally handler that exception and throws `InternalAuthenticationServiceException`. The issue is, I am not able to catch that exception in my central place where I customize the response in case of errors. I am using `@ControllerAdvice` for that, but it seems Spring just ignore and always send default "Internal Server Error".

Comment: Please, you can provide more information such as your code?

Comment: As the name `@ControllerAdvice` implies it is for controller/handlers NOT filters. Those execute too early in the proces and aren't processed by the exception handlers.

Answer (score 0):

in order to capture a "failed authentication" just override the method `unsuccessfulAuthentication` in your **filter**

```java
@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response,
    AuthenticationException failed)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

    //handle errors
}
```